# Puppet PostgresQL management

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, puppet, packer, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to provision an EC2 instance using puppet. In the process I have downloaded the **puppetlabs-postgresql** module from puppetlabs. Since I'm fairly new to puppet, i do not want to manage my database by creating classes in my **site.pp file** located in **/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp**. Rather I want to have a module call **database** in **/etc/puppet/modules/database**. 
What I have done so far is create an **init.pp file** in **/etc/puppet/modules/database**. Below is the content of my **init.pp** file :

```
class database {
    # resources
    postgresql::globals{'globals':
        version             => '9.3',
        manage_package_repo => true,
        encoding            => 'UTF8',
        locale              => 'it_IT.utf8',

    }

    postgresql::server{'server':
        ensure           => 'present',
        listen_addresses => '*',
        manage_firewall  => true,
    }

    postgresql::server::contrib{'contrib':
        package_ensure => 'present',
    }
}
```

And then in my **/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp** file i have included the **database class** as below :

```
node default {
    include localusers
    include database
}
```

However i keep getting an error :

```
   Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type postgresql::globals at /etc/puppet.manifests/init.pp:12
```

Please what is the correct way to make use of the postgresql classes and resources in my own module and create a database in the module as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are a few issues with how you're using the postgresql module. The reason you're getting the `Invalid resource type` error is that you're trying to use `postgresql::globals` as a defined type when it's actually a class. You have the same issue with the other two classes you're using. Try this...

```
class database {
    # set global defaults before creating server
    class { 'postgresql::globals':
        version             => '9.3',
        manage_package_repo => true,
        encoding            => 'UTF8',
        locale              => 'it_IT.utf8',
    }->
    class { 'postgresql::server':
        listen_addresses => '*',
        manage_firewall  => true,
    }

    # install the postgresql contrib package
    class { 'postgresql::server::contrib':
        package_ensure => 'present',
    }

    # create database with user and default permissions
    postgresql::server::db { 'my_awesome_db':
        user     => 'my_db_user',
        password => 'puppetRocks',
    }
}
```

In the [reference section of the module documentation](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/postgresql#reference), there's a breakdown of the classes and resources (a.k.a. defined types). The `postgresql::server::db` type that I used is the simplest way to create a database, user, and permissions all at once. There are separate types available for each of those to provide more fine-grained control.

Comment: thanks alot, its solved my problem, except that the "ensure" parameter does not exist for the **postgresql::server**  class. Apart from that, am happy with your help

Comment: Good catch. I just fixed that.